# Trying to edit a smart object by using my own image, but it shows up massive and I can't scale it down

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I'm using this template:

[image] ([source](http://dribbble.com/shots/727175-iPhone-5-Template?list=searches&tag=photoshop_template))

I have my own image that is 1136 * 640: the size of the smart object that depicts the contents of the iPhone 5 screen. When I drop my image onto the smart object, it is 1.5x the normal size (stretched) and I can't use Free Transform, as it's greyed out.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you double clicking on the smart object layer (it is highlighted below)?

[image]

double clicking it will open the smart object as so:

[image]

I used the template with this image from a search for `1136 x 640`:

[image]

and my results are this:

[image]

works fine for me so I think you are entering in the wrong settings or are mixing up the `width x height`